# Align to bottom of flexbox

Tags: html, css

I want to align my View button to end of my box, but i couldnt found anyway

```css
.filmbox {
    overflow:hidden;
    border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color:rgb(36, 36, 36);
    width:180px;
    height:413px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.filminfo{
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-6px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.view{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px;    
    margin-bottom:4px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    width:140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filmbox">
    <img class="poster" src="{{x.poster.url}}">
    <div class="filminfo">
        <div class="info">
        <p class="rating">Ratings: {{ x.rating }}/5.0<img src="{% static 'image/rating.png' %}"><br>{{ x.title }}</p>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="view">
        <a href="movie/{{x.id}}">View</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried someway in the style, like position absolute, or align item, but they didnt work

im just want to align view button to the bottom of film box

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `position: relative;` to the `.filmbox` class instead of `.filminfo` if you are trying to place the view button (`<a href="movie/{{x.id}}">View</a>`) at the end of the filmbox.

```
.filmbox {
   overflow:hidden;
   border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
   background-color:rgb(36, 36, 36);
   width:180px;
   height:413px;
   margin-right:10px;
   display:inline-block;
   position: relative; <!-- code updated here -->
}

.filminfo{
   <!-- code updated here -->
   margin-top:-6px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

The concept is when you set an element to `position: absolute;` it will positioned relative to the nearest ancestor element which is positioned. If there are no ancestor elements with such properties the absolute positioning would be relative to the document itself.

For more details refer to this [w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

I hope you find this helpful.